# $\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{{-|x|}^n}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to prove that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{{-|x|}^n}dx = V(B_{n}(0,1))$ using induction and Cavalieri's principle.

Notice that $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-|x|}dx = 2 = V(B_1(0, 1))$ so the basis of our induction is true.

Now suppose that for some $k-1$ we have $\int_{\mathbb R^{k-1}}e^{{-|x|}^{k-1}}dx = V(B_{k-1}(0,1))$

We want to calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^{k}}e^{-{|x|}^{k}}dx$, we can choose to extract it by spheres since this is a positive function, so this will be equal to $$\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_{x_1^2+\dots x_k^2 \leq r^2}e^{-|x|^{k}}dx.$$

Consider the intersection of this sphere with the plane $x_k = t$. From Cavalieri's principle:

$$
\int_{x_1^2+\dots x_k^2 \leq r^2} e^{-|x|^{k}}dx
= \int_{-r}^r
  \left( \int_{x_1^2+\dots+x_{k-1}^2 \leq r^2-t^2}
              e^{-(x_1^2+\dots+x_{k-1}^2+t^2)^{k/2}}dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}
  \right) dt$$

Not sure where to go from here....

Comment: Make rather a polar coordinate change?

Comment: I don't think that's the intended way. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Cavalieri's principle means this way:
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{-|x|^n}\mathrm dx =\int_0^1 \text{vol}\{x:e^{-|x|^n}\ge t\}\mathrm dt.
$$ (Explanation: imagine we are given $z=e^{-x^2-y^2}$. We can calculate the volume under the graph by cutting it along $z=t\in (0,1)$, calculating the area of the cross-section and re-gathering it.) This gives
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1 \text{vol}\{x:e^{-|x|^n}\ge t\}\mathrm dt&=& \int_0^1 \text{vol}\left[(-\ln t)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot B_n\right]\mathrm dt\\&=&\text{vol}(B_n) \int_0^1 (-\ln t)\mathrm dt\\&=&\text{vol}(B_n),
\end{eqnarray}$$where $B_n$ is a $n$-dimensional unit ball and $c\cdot B_n = \{cx\;|\;x\in B_n\}=B_n(0,c)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Aren't we supposed to look at cross sections? The valid "height" or $x_k$ coordinate for these cross sections is between $(-r,r)$ as $r$ tends to infinity? why $(0,1)$?

Comment: @OriaGruber Yes, we do the cross section horizontally. Since $0< e^{-|x|^n}\le 1$, $0<t\le 1$ is sufficient. For example, imagine $z=e^{-x^2-y^2}$. We can calculate the volume under the graph of it by cutting it along $z=c \in (0,1)$ and gathering it. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: @OriaGruber You can prove $\int_X fd\mu = \int_0^\infty \mu(\{|f| > \lambda\}) d\lambda$ for any measure space $(X,\mu)$ and any $f \in L^1$, by first proving it for simple functions and then doing linear combinations and taking limits.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes! That is what exactly I did. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: May I ask one more question @Song - Why $\geq t$? Shouldn't it be equal $t$ since we are looking at a cross section with height $t$?

Comment: @OriaGruber Umm ... I think the reason is: if we write $e^{-|x|^n}=t$, then it means $|x| = (-\ln t)^{1/n}$. But it is a sphere, not a ball, and hence has $0$ $n$-dimensional volume. So it should be $\ge t$ to be right.

Comment: @OriaGruber you have a good question. Note that the volume of the set where $e^{-|x|^n}$ is equal to $t$ is $0$, so that wouldn't work. What you are really suggesting is to integrate the *area* of the set where $e^{-|x|^n}$ is equal to $t$. This is the same as integrating the volume of the set where $e^{-|x|^n}$ is at least $t$, since "the derivative of volume is area".

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. We are integrating over areas of all cross sections. I got the correct answer. Thank you both.